# If Mu is a projection matrix, how can I show that Mu^2=Mu by direct computation?

Tags: linear-algebra

The definition of Mu, or the projection matrix, I am working with is Mu(a)=Pu(a). Let's say that a set of vectors (v1, v2.....vm) is an orthonormal basis of U. Then, I can calculate Pu(a) by doing (v1*a)v1+(v2*a)v2+....(vm*a)vm. Eventually, I would be able to conclude that Mu=VV^T. Am I on the right track? How can I conclude that Mu^2=Mu otherwise? Thanks

Comment: In your definition of projection matrix, what are $P_u$ and $a$?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach appears to be on the right track.  The general expression for a projection matrix is:

$$
P=A\left(A^{T}A\right)^{-1}A^{T}
$$

so from this you can write:

$$
P^{2}=A\left(A^{T}A\right)^{-1}A^{T}A\left(A^{T}A\right)^{-1}A^{T}
$$.

Since we get a cancellation due to $\left(A^{T}A\right)^{-1}A^{T}A=I$ in the middle, this yields:

$$
P^{2}=A\left(A^{T}A\right)^{-1}A^{T}=P
$$.

I hope this helps.